# Cannot load project on android studio after upgrading macOS 12.4 react-native

Tags: react-native, android-studio, macos-monterey

I updated MacOS Monterey 12.4 and showing this error on Android Studio

```
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node" (in directory "{projectFolder}/android/app"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
Cause: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because android studio couldn't find node and should run through terminal.

If you are using Mac you can run Android studio using This command in terminal

1. Run this open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
2. Then sync Gradle

And this will solve the problem.

Comment: Already tried this method, but not work on me. Still same.